# Solution of the differential equation $(x^2\sin^3y – y^2 \cos x)dx + (x^3\cos y\sin^2y–2y\sin x)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the differential equation $$(x^2\sin^3y – y^2 \cos x)dx + (x^3\cos y\sin^2y–2y\sin x)dy = 0$$

I am not able to solve it because it involves multiple function viz trigonometric etc.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The first order differential equation is given in the form

$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$
where
$$M(x,y)=x^2\sin^3y – y^2 \cos x, ~~N(x,y)=x^3\cos y\sin^2y–2y\sin x$$

and

$$\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y}= 3 x^2 \sin^2y \cos y - 2 y \cos x$$
$$\frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x}= 3 x^2 \sin^2 y \cos y - 2 y \cos x$$

therefore the differential equation is [exact](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/differential-equations/first-order-equations/exact-equations).

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:} ~$
Observe that,
$$ x^{2} {\sin}^{3}{y} \text{dx}+ x^{3} \cos{y} ~{\sin}^{2}{y} \text{dy}=\frac{1}{3}d(x^{3} {\sin}^{3}{y}) $$ 
$$ y^{2} \cos{x} \text{dx} +2y \sin{x} \text{dy}=d(y^{2} \sin{x}) $$